# Dynamically edit .svg file that's set as background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I added an svg image to the background of a div.

```
        div#cover{
            background-image:url('dwm.svg');
        }
```

I would like to know if there is any way I could dynamically edit certain aspects of this svg such as fill, stroke , etc.

Comment: You can try having the svg as part of the DOM, do the modification and then set the background as a data uri of the modified svg pulled from the DOM

Comment: Interesting, how would I set the background image as an svg in the DOM?

Comment: load the svg into a div, modify the svg data, get the div's contents, make a data uri out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try having the svg as part of the DOM, do the modification and then set the background as a data uri of the modified svg pulled from the DOM.
While this might be kind of hacky it works

```
$('#bg').css('background-image', 'url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+btoa($('#svg').html())+')');
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#fill').attr('fill', '#ff00ff');
    $('#bg').css('background-image', 'url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+btoa($('#svg').html())+')');
});
```

```html
<div id="bg"></div>
<div id="svg">[svg data]</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zSRW5/

If you don't want to embed the svg you can always use ajax to get it.

Answer (score 0):

No. I believe you can only do that if you embed the SVG within the page and reference it and even then, you would have to change the background value to something else and back to the reference, due to browser bugs.

Comment: I know! Please, however, do not forget to accept the answer if nothing else comes up. :)